# xcode 12 swift 5 how to check if the value of a variable is in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array

```
let flies = [".pdf",".doc",".docx",".txt",".xls",".xlsx",".mp3",".wav",".aif",".mp4",".mov",".avi",".h26"]
```

and a url transformed into a string

```
let fullnru = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString // example "https://www.example.com/123.pdf"
```

When I do

```
 if( flies.contains(fullnru) ) { do something }
```

it doesn't work :(

I want to test if the url as .pdf or .mov

how to fix this ?

Comment: Well, your array doesn't actually contain `"https://www.example.com/123.pdf"`. Did you expect it to?

Comment: @Sweeper Hi, to clarify, I want to test if the url as .pdf or .mov, etc to do something

Comment: `flies.contains(fuller.suffix(4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the extension using [`pathExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1410208-pathextension):

```
if let fullnru = navigationAction.request.url?.pathExtension,
    files.contains(fullnru) {
    // do something
}
```

Note that `pathExtension` returns the extension without the `.` character, so your array should be:

```
let files = ["pdf","doc","docx","txt","xls","xlsx","mp3","wav","aif","mp4","mov","avi","h26"]
```

As Leo Dabus pointed out in the comments, you should declare `files` as a set:

```
let files = Set(
    ["pdf","doc","docx","txt","xls","xlsx","mp3","wav","aif","mp4","mov","avi","h26"]
)
```

EDIT:

It seems like you actually want to find if the URL contains any elements of an array/set:

```
if let fullnru = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString,
    files.contains(where: { fullnru.contains($0) }) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: And considering that the order doesn't matter and there would be no duplicates in the collection this should be declared as a set instead of an array.

Comment: this can also be written as `let files: Set = ["pdf", "doc", "docx", ...]`

Comment: it's ok for files with a dot ........ ????? but for other case where it's not .pdf but If I wan to test if the url contains /blablabla/ for example ?

Comment: @Jintor You are not making a lot of sense here... If you want to test if the url contains "blablabla" (which probably should be another question), do `absoluteString.contains("blablabla")`

Comment: @Sweeper it's because I do more PHP programming, I made myself a function where I do `if finderFunction($url,array('.pdf','blablabla','coucou')){ do something }` where the custom function do a `foreach stripos !== false` .... and I wanted to apply the same thinking in swift that I'm new

Comment: @Jintor So does `finderFunction` return true if any of the things in the array is present in the URL? Or does it return true if all the things in the array are present in the URL?

Comment: @Sweeper it will return true if the url contains any element of an array like this `function finderFunction ($string,$array) {
 foreach ($array as $a) {
  if ( stripos($string,$a) !== false ) { return true; }
 }
}`